# How to create core in solr 7 when using Basic Authentication

Tags: solr

I'm using basic authentication in my solr project. I want to create new core but it gives me this error.

```
ERROR: Solr requires authentication for http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system. Please supply valid credentials. HTTP code=401
```

I'm creating the core like this

```
solr create -c StorageCore -credentials solr:SolrRocks
```

How can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

[image: Mt solr.in.cmd]

Answer (score 1):

That command argument is only supported when enabling authentication through the command line tool.

For [using the control script with basic auth](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/basic-authentication-plugin.html#using-the-solr-control-script-with-basic-auth):

> **Using the Solr Control Script with Basic Auth**
>
> Add the following line
> to the solr.in.sh or solr.in.cmd file. This example tells the bin/solr
> command line to to use "basic" as the type of authentication, and to
> pass credentials with the user-name "solr" and password "SolrRocks":
>
> ```
> SOLR_AUTH_TYPE="basic"
> SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:SolrRocks"
> ```

Comment: I tried to do this in command line but it gives me this error `invalid command-line option :SOLR_AUTH_TYPE `

Comment: You don't run those statements directly on the command line in the example described, you configure them in the solr.in.cmd file. I'm guessing they might get picked up if you `SET` them (i.e. `SET SOLR_AUTH_TYPE ...` for Windows) or `export` them (Linux/OS X) first.

Comment: I checked my solr.in.cmd and it already configured like this but in command line giving error. I'll add screen shot of my solr.in.cmd.